# Text_Change Event Not Raised

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, label, textchanged

I have the following piece of code:

```
private sub xtoy()
    lbl_packed_as.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Me.DatasetProduct, "tbl_products.packed_fresh_or_frozen"))
end sub
```

and this:

```
Private Sub lbl_packed_as_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lbl_packed_as.TextChanged
    Select Case lbl_packed_as.Text
        Case "FR"
            rdb_fresh.Checked = True
        Case "FZ"
            rdb_frozen.Checked = True
        Case "NA"
            rdb_na.Checked = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

At this point of time the label `lbl_packed_as.Visible=false` so I can't reach the above method. If I set `lbl_packed_as.Visible=True` then the above method is working. I don't want to show the `lbl_packed_as` label on my screen.

Any help?

Comment: Put it off-screen (Left=-1000, Top=-1000) and leave it visible

Comment: @Steve that works fine,  can please elaborate the problem that makes it happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have said in comments, you could change the location of the Label to a point that is not inside the viewable area of your form.

I suggest to put your label, using the designer window, in a position where you could see it when you look at your form through the designer. Then, in code, move it to a different location. You could do this at the Form_Load event with this single line.

```
' Move the control to a position before the top and left border
' In this way it is not visible to the end user but still retains 
' its visible property to allow databindings to function
lbl_packed_as.Location = new Point(-1000, -1000)
```

Comment: this solution worked for one application, i have the same kind of approach to another module too with different dataset and different labels its not working for that

Comment: Not sure what could prevent this approach to work on the same situation.

Comment: I will try to figure it out, Thanks for the solution , Thanks again